# MySQL hyphen/minus character in place of equals in where clause gives unexpected result

Tags: mysql, sql, operators

When typing an SQL query for use with MySQL I accidentally mistyped a hyphen/minus sign (-) in place of an equals sign (=).  This resulted in the query being:

```
select id, field from table where id - 9;
```

instead of the intended:

```
select id, field from table where id = 9;
```

However, instead of giving me the expected syntax error it gave me a result set.  What it gave me seems to be the inverse of what I intended as if i had issued:

```
select id, field from table where id <> 9;
```

The id column is of type int and the table is using the innodb storage engine.  If I try the query against a table with an id column of type unsigned bigint I get an error though not the syntax error I expected:

> ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range

I have seen this behaviour in both version 5.7 (on Ubuntu 18.04) and 8.0 (on Ubuntu 22.04) of MySQL and with STRICT_TRANS_TABLES set in the mode.

Can anyone tell me why `id - number` seems to be interpreted as `id <> number` rather than a syntax error before I potentially embarrass myself by reporting it to MySQL as a bug?

I've tried searching the web for similar issues but to no avail.

Regards,
Nachtkinder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL treats the `WHERE`clause as a number constant

0 Is `FALSE` and every other number is `TRUE`

And when the `WHERE`is  `TRUE` it returns **all**  rows

ANd of course when `FALSE` nothing

see the example below

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (id int, field int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1,1),(7,7) , (10,10)
> ```

> ```
> select id, field from table1 where id - 9;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | field
> -: | ----:
>  1 |     1
>  7 |     7
> 10 |    10
> ```

> ```
> select id, field from table1 where 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | field
> -: | ----:
>  1 |     1
>  7 |     7
> 10 |    10
> ```

> ```
> select id, field from table1 where 0;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | field
> -: | ----:
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5565d3be09a099801ed9a9bd71a376d1)*

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  I had considered that MySQL might be subtracting the number from each id value and casting the result as a boolean.  I hadn't realised that it would consider negative integer values to be true.

Comment: you could have seen it as id 9 would not be shown.